# Set one variable of class when other variable is set?

Tags: java, android, performance, gson

I retrieving data from json file and using gson to convert it to POJO class.
I have two variable "*instancename*" and "*instanceid*" which i didn't get from json response. SO i have to set when i get list "Columns" value.

```
public class Row implements Serializable{
@SerializedName("ElementInstanceID")
@Expose
private String elementInstanceID;
@SerializedName("Columns")
@Expose
@Ignore
private List<String> columns = null;

private String roominstancename;

private int roominstanceid;

public Row(){
    Log.d("ROW","1");
    update();
}

public String getRoominstancename() {
    return roominstancename;
}

public void setRoominstancename(String roominstancename) {
    this.roominstancename = roominstancename;
}

public int getRoominstanceid() {
    return roominstanceid;
}

public void setRoominstanceid(int roominstanceid) {
    this.roominstanceid = roominstanceid;
}


public String getElementInstanceID() {
    return elementInstanceID;
}

public void setElementInstanceID(String elementInstanceID) {
    this.elementInstanceID = elementInstanceID;
}

public List<String> getColumns() {
    return columns;
}



public void setColumns(List<String> columns) {
    this.columns = columns;
    setInstance(columns);
}

public void setInstance(List<String> columns){
    setRoominstancename(columns.get(0));
    setRoominstanceid(Integer.parseInt(columns.get(1)));
}

public void update(){
    if (columns != null && columns.size() >= 0){
        setInstance(columns);
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Element ID"+elementInstanceID;
}
}
```

Code to retrieve ROW object

```
final List<Row> rows = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(rowArray.toString(), Row[].class));
```

I am trying to update after i am getting list rows

```
 for (Row row:rows) {
            row.update();
        }
```

Is there any way to make it efficient?

Comment: @YayoArellano Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to consider 
***observer design pattern***.
 From simple definition:
Observer pattern is used when there is one-to-many relationship between objects such as if one object is modified, its depenedent objects are to be notified automatically.
You can visit this link, there are some great examples for [this pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm).